# Property of custom NSObject is nil when set from another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, keychain

The title might be a bit a bit confusing, sorry. I'll try to keep the question as short as possible but provide code and examples of my problem.

I have an app with login functionality. When logging in, I make a request to my database and parse the response, then set values for my `account` object (such as name, password, etc). I'm using `UYLPasswordManager` to store values in iOS Keychain. Here's an example of my setter/getter for the email (all other property setter/getters use the same code):

```
- (void)setUsername:(NSString *)username {
    UYLPasswordManager *keyManager = [UYLPasswordManager sharedInstance];
    [keyManager registerKey:username forIdentifier:AccountDataUsernameIdentifier];
}

- (NSString *)username {
    UYLPasswordManager *keyManager = [UYLPasswordManager sharedInstance];
    return [keyManager keyForIdentifier:AccountDataUsernameIdentifier];
}
```

Once saved in the keychain, I call a `save` function for my `AccountData` class which saves the values to `NSUserDefaults`, like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.username forKey:AccountDataUsernameKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

So when logging in, typical flow would parse the data response and create an `NSDictionary`, and I can start setting `account.username = dict[@"username"]` and other values, then call `[account save]` to save to keychain and `NSUserDefaults`.

This works well for existing `account` properties. But I now want to store an email address if one exists in my database. So everything is the same as before - parse from server, check if dictionary contains a value for `email`, if it's empty then I present a view controller modally. User can then enter their email and submit. I make a request to my database, save the email to the database, then I need to store it in iOS. This is where the problem is.

When the user submits, they are presented with a successful alert, tapping OK dismisses the view and app continues as normal. The AlertAction calls a method which sets `account.email = self.emailString` (set from the textfield), then I call `[account save]` which should save all the properties for that account in my AccountData object class.

```
- (void)setEmailAddressForAccount:(AccountData *)account {
if (!account.email) {
    [account setEmail:self.emailString];

    // Present successful update alert
...
    [account save]; // this is in the UIAlertAction handler, when user taps OK
```

When `setEmail:email` has finished storing to iOS keychain, I can print `self.email` at the end of the setter, and it is `nil`. But the string being sent in is not `nil`. This then results in setting a `nil` value for the email when `[account save]` is called. This method saves all my values to `NSUserDefaults`, here is the one for email:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.email forKey:AccountDataEmail];
```

If I set a breakpoint and print `self.email` in the `[account save]` method, it's nil. All other properties are set correctly and are not nil. I can set/get values of the `account` object anywhere when needed, but `email` is always `nil`.

Note: The AccountData object has a `reloadAccount` method which inits a new `account` object - it gets called a few times during the login/email capture process. Could this be causing the issue? There are times during the login process where there are two instances of an `account` object.

Please, can someone help me, I'm getting frustrated because it seems like such a small addition to my code should not take this long to implement, and should not be causing me such a headache.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly related to how you are managing the `account` object... Tough to say without seeing what all is going on. *"[account save]; // this is in the UIAlertAction handler, when user taps OK"* -- are you sure you still have the same `account` object there?

Comment: Yea sounds like an empty account object was passed to setEmailAddressForAccount method. Logically there should be one account object, so you should declare account property in your class that way only one instance of it exist.